# Real life problems solved using CPLEX

Tags: cplex

What are the real life applications of CPLEX? What are some of the big problems CPLEX is used for?

Comment: X-post [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=eb85dc72-72ef-401d-95cb-da71c8ceb633).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great opportunity to sing the praises of some amazing software.

Basically, software like CPLEX, FICO Xpress, and Gurobi (and there are others) are behind an amazing number of things that you take for granted in every day life. So you will find that almost all really big manufacturers will have something like this for production and supply chain planning and scheduling. Similarly for retailers. Also transport planning and management.

So when you go to the shops, you will be buying stuff where the production planning probably used this stuff. And I mean almost anything, from milk production to televisions, clothes, cars, whatever. It will have been transported from raw material sources to factories to warehouses which were sited to minimise transport costs or similar. Stock levels for inventory are planned using this software. The mix of vehicles in the transport fleets is planned like this, and the choice of which vehicles to use for which routes, and even the routes themselves are planned using this type of software.

Shop layouts in supermarkets (what goes on which shelf in which aisle) is planned like this. The planes that you ride on are sequenced from flight to flight, airport to airport using this kind of software, to keep flight crews hours within regulations, fit in with maintenance schedules, and minimise fuel costs. Even the layout of airports (the mix of different types of arrival and departure gates) is done using this software. Sequencing planes on air corridors is also done like this. Banks and finance houses use this stuff to optimise portfolios, strategies for loans and debt recovery. Your pension (if you have one) is managed the same basic software technology. Your health services will also be planned and resourced using the same ideas. The mix of adverts that you see when you watch TV is planned like this. I could easily go on with many more examples.

Truly this is **amazing** software technology. Most people have never heard of it, but this stuff actually runs the world we live in.

It can be used for all of the following real life applications:

- Workforce planning for air traffic controllers
- Aircrew allocation for airlines
- Defence force long-term strategic planning
- Alloy blending for high-spec alloys
- Slotting adverts in commercial breaks on TV
- Product pricing
- Allocation of highly demanded products to clients